# Emulator are not starting after updating gradle to latest version

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-emulator, emulation

I am facing an issue while running flutter project, everything was working fine before I have added image picker library, I have tried migrating to android x, a pop up said "
No usage found for this project", Please help I am stuck for hours a go.

GRADLE FILES:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.sample_gallery"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}


distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip











buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()

    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {  url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

ERROR:

Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.jar
   > Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.5.0/builder-3.5.0.jar
   > Could not find crash.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/crash/26.5.0/crash-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.5.0/lint-gradle-api-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/3.5.0/gradle-api-3.5.0.jar
   > Could not find databinding-compiler-common.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler-common/3.5.0/databinding-compiler-common-3.5.0.jar
   > Could not find manifest-merger.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/26.5.0/manifest-merger-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find sdk-common.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/26.5.0/sdk-common-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find builder-test-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:3.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/3.5.0/builder-test-api-3.5.0.jar
   > Could not find ddmlib.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/26.5.0/ddmlib-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find tracker.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/tracker/26.5.0/tracker-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find sdklib.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/26.5.0/sdklib-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find layoutlib-api.jar (com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/26.5.0/layoutlib-api-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find dvlib.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/26.5.0/dvlib-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find repository.jar (com.android.tools:repository:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/repository/26.5.0/repository-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find shared.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/shared/26.5.0/shared-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find common.jar (com.android.tools:common:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/common/26.5.0/common-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find jetifier-processor.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta04).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-processor/1.0.0-beta04/jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta04.jar
   > Could not find bundletool.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.9.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.9.0/bundletool-0.9.0.jar
   > Could not find jetifier-core.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta04).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-core/1.0.0-beta04/jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta04.jar
   > Could not find protos.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/26.5.0/protos-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find builder-model.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/3.5.0/builder-model-3.5.0.jar
   > Could not find apkzlib.jar (com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:3.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apkzlib/3.5.0/apkzlib-3.5.0.jar
   > Could not find apksig.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:3.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/3.5.0/apksig-3.5.0.jar
   > Could not find annotations.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/26.5.0/annotations-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find databinding-common.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:3.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-common/3.5.0/databinding-common-3.5.0.jar
   > Could not find baseLibrary.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.5.0/baseLibrary-3.5.0.jar
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetifier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.jar
   > Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.5.0/builder-3.5.0.jar
   > Could not find crash.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/crash/26.5.0/crash-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.5.0/lint-gradle-api-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/3.5.0/gradle-api-3.5.0.jar
   > Could not find databinding-compiler-common.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler-common/3.5.0/databinding-compiler-common-3.5.0.jar
   > Could not find manifest-merger.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/26.5.0/manifest-merger-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find sdk-common.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/26.5.0/sdk-common-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find builder-test-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:3.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/3.5.0/builder-test-api-3.5.0.jar
   > Could not find ddmlib.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/26.5.0/ddmlib-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find tracker.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/tracker/26.5.0/tracker-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find sdklib.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/26.5.0/sdklib-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find layoutlib-api.jar (com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/26.5.0/layoutlib-api-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find dvlib.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/26.5.0/dvlib-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find repository.jar (com.android.tools:repository:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/repository/26.5.0/repository-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find shared.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/shared/26.5.0/shared-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find common.jar (com.android.tools:common:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/common/26.5.0/common-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find jetifier-processor.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta04).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-processor/1.0.0-beta04/jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta04.jar
   > Could not find bundletool.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.9.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.9.0/bundletool-0.9.0.jar
   > Could not find jetifier-core.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta04).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-core/1.0.0-beta04/jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta04.jar
   > Could not find protos.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/26.5.0/protos-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find builder-model.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/3.5.0/builder-model-3.5.0.jar
   > Could not find apkzlib.jar (com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:3.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apkzlib/3.5.0/apkzlib-3.5.0.jar
   > Could not find apksig.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:3.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/3.5.0/apksig-3.5.0.jar
   > Could not find annotations.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/26.5.0/annotations-26.5.0.jar
   > Could not find databinding-common.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:3.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-common/3.5.0/databinding-common-3.5.0.jar
   > Could not find baseLibrary.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.5.0/baseLibrary-3.5.0.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

DEPENDENCIES:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.4
  image_picker: ^0.6.0+10
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

**EDIT**
The error was disappeared after updating gradle and android plugin to latest version, now the build is successful but emulator ca not be launched.

**SOLVED**
The errors was gone after I updated Android SDK platform tools, Android Emulator and Intel packages, then I have created new project using flutter and it worked like charm!

Comment: You're trying to use a version of the library which is 2 years old. Have you tried updating the library to the latest version?

Comment: Which library? Gradle? Do I have to update the android studio as well ? I have updated the image picker to : ^0.8.1+1 an error still occured A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0).